# Prevent other winforms to override parent winform properties

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a list of winforms

```
mainWinform
winform1
winform2
winform3 ...
```

`winform1`, `winform2` and `winform3` are inheriting `mainWinform` design

I have set some `winform` like:

`winform1` to:

```
maximizeBox = false
FormBorderStyle to Sizable
```

`winform2` to:

```
maximizeBox = true
FormBorderStyle to fixed
```

Since I am inheriting from `mainWinform` is there a way I can set every `winform` to 
`maximizeBox = true`, `FormBorderStyle to Sizable` by setting `mainWinform` even `winform1` have set it to `maximizeBox = false` `FormBorderStyle to Sizable`?

Comment: simply set the properties in the constructor of your `mainWinform`, other derived forms will override those properties if needed.

Comment: @KingKing That totally and completely doesn't answer OP's question. He's asking if there is a way to PREVENT derived forms from overriding those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent inherited forms from override parent settings, you can try to override `OnStyleChanged` in parent form class:

```
protected override void OnStyleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MaximizeBox!=true) this.MaximizeBox = true;
    base.OnStyleChanged(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set these properties in the constructor of inherited `form`s. For example:

```
public winform
{
    //in this way you can inherit parent form properties and set them to child form
    this.MaximizeBox = base.MaximizeBox;
    this.FormBorderStyle = base.FormBorderStyle;
    //or if you want to set it something else, then do like this
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}
```

You can change the values as you need. But you will have to put the code in constructor.